# Can a company director simply appoint another company director?

Tags: corporate-law

I found the following article in my company constitution:

> The directors of the company may appoint a person as a director of the
>   company. The company must confirm such an appointment by resolution
>   passed at a general meeting within 2 months after the appointment is
>   made. If the company does not confirm the appointment, the person
>   ceases to be a director of the company upon the expiration of 2 months
>   after the appointment was made.

Does this mean any director can appoint another director and that director can serve for 2 months without approval?

Won't this provide avenue for a board coup? Meaning a director can simply elect directors to support him and make changes to the company constitution.

Comment: Under the laws of what country/state?

Comment: I'm in Australia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you quoted does not say "**a**" director can appoint a director. It says "**the directors**", plural, can appoint a director. I assume that would be by a vote. Elsewhere in the document it might or might not be made clear if this requires only a majority and/or if this is only in cases to fill a vacancy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Appointment of directors is by the board. A board meeting needs quorum, and this will not ever be one person.

So no, one director cannot appoint other directors.